# Dropping observations after a certain condition is met in SAS

Tags: sas, delete-row, retain

This is an extension of an earlier question. ([Drop observations once condition is met by multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268829/drop-observations-once-condition-is-met-by-multiple-variables)).

I have the following data and used one of the existing answered questions to solve my data problem but could not get what I want. Here is what I have in my data

- Amt1 is populated when the Evt_type is Fee
- Amt2 is populated when the Evt_type is REF1/REF2
- I don't want to display any observations after the last Flag='Y'
- If there is no Flag='Y' then I want all the observations for that id (e.g. id=102)
- **I want to display if the next row for that id is a Fee followed by REF1/REF2 after flag='Y' (e.g. id=101) However I don't want if there is no REF1/REF2 (e.g.id=103)**

Have:

```
   id   Date        Evt_Type   Flag   Amt1   Amt2
  101  2/2/2019      Fee              5
  101  2/3/2019      REF1      Y             5
  101  2/4/2019      Fee              10
  101  2/6/2019      REF2      Y             10
  101  2/7/2019      Fee               4
  101  2/8/2019      REF1
  102  2/2/2019      Fee              25
  102  2/2/2019      REF1      N      25
  103  2/3/2019      Fee              10
  103  2/4/2019      REF1      Y             10
  103  2/5/2019      Fee              10
```

Want:

```
  id   Date        Evt_Type   Flag   Amt1   Amt2
 101  2/2/2019      Fee              5
 101  2/3/2019      REF1      Y             5
 101  2/4/2019      Fee              10
 101  2/6/2019      REF2      Y             10
 101  2/7/2019      Fee               4
 101  2/8/2019      REF1
 102  2/2/2019      Fee              25
 102  2/2/2019      REF1      N      25
 103  2/3/2019      Fee              10
 103  2/4/2019      REF1      Y             10
```

I tried the following

```
data want;
  _max_n_with_Y = 1e12;

  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
  if flag='Y' then _max_n_with_Y = _n_;
 end;

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
   set have;
   if _n_ <= _max_n_with_Y then OUTPUT;
  end;
 drop _:;
run;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In group 103 the last `Y` row in the group has a subsequent `Fee` but that is not followed by a `Ref#` -- Why does `Want` group 103 have the Fee after Y?  In group 101 you show `Want` with two rows after the last `Y` row -- that does not agree with the question condition "I want to display if the **next row** for that id is a Fee followed by REF#.

Comment: My bad. I corrected it for 103. but for 101, it is Fee followed by Ref1 after flag='Y' (rows 5 and 6 from have) so I want these in my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important 'landmark' is the row with `flag='Y'`

The extra criteria for outputting rows *post-landmark* complicate the *state machine* being coded to track (or compute) the row number (`_n_`) for last output of the group.

The `row='Y'` state is easily known.  Unconditional use of `LAG` can be used to examine the post-Y state.  SAS `IF` statements do not have short circuit evaluation, so as long as the `LAG` is not in a subordinate `THEN` clause, the `LAG` stacks will be appropriate for the task.

Example:

```
data have;
attrib
  id format=4.
  date informat=mmddyy10. format=mmddyy10.
  evt_type length=$4
  flag length=$1
  amt1 amt2 format=4.
;
input
   id   Date        Evt_Type   Flag   Amt1   Amt2; datalines;
  101  2/2/2019      Fee       .      5      .
  101  2/3/2019      REF1      Y      .      5
  101  2/4/2019      Fee       .      10     .
  101  2/6/2019      REF2      Y      .      10
  101  2/7/2019      Fee       .       4     .
  101  2/8/2019      REF1      .      .      .
  102  2/2/2019      Fee       .      25     .
  102  2/2/2019      REF1      N      25     .
  103  2/3/2019      Fee       .      10     .
  103  2/4/2019      REF1      Y      .      10
  103  2/5/2019      Fee       .      10     .
;

data want;
  _y_n = 1e12;

  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;

    if flag='Y' then _y_n = _n_;

    /* rule: post Y output of two rows should only occur once, and at the rows
     * immediately succeeding the Y row
     */
    if _n_ = _y_n + 2            /* is this row 2 after a Y */
      and lag(evt_type) = 'Fee'  /* is first row after Y Fee */
      and evt_type =: 'REF'      /* is second row after Y REF# */
    then 
      _upto_n = _n_;
  end;

  _upto_n = max (_upto_n, _y_n);

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
   set have;
   if _n_ <= _upto_n then OUTPUT;
  end;

  drop _:;
run;
```

Note, regarding:

```
if _n_ = _y_n + 2            /* is this row 2 after a Y */
  and lag(evt_type) = 'Fee'  /* is first row after Y Fee */
  and evt_type =: 'REF'      /* is second row after Y REF# */
then 
  _upto_n = _n_;
```

For the row 2 after Y,

```
  LAG2(<var>) is the <var> value from the Y row
  LAG (<var>) is the <var> value from the Y row+1
       <var>  is the <var> value from the Y row+2, which is the current row
```

Comment: Thanks Richard.. _y_n+2 is checking only the next 2 rows after ‘Y’. Can this be dynamic? Sometimes it is 2 rows or 4 rows after ‘Y’

Comment: So, you really want, in each group, *all the rows up to the last flag="Y" and all the subsequent rows up to the last `evt_type` row-pair "Fee/REF#"* ?  If so, just change equality test at `_n_ = _y_n + 2` to `>=`